# Is qiskit.pulse.SamplePulse deprecated?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, textbook-and-exercises

I'm currently following along the book "Learn Quantum Computing with Python and IBM Quantum Experience" by Rodert Loredo and I am at chapter 8 - Generating pulse schedules on hardware. The book material imports something called a `SamplePulse`, which class however seems to be moved to a new location in the latest Qiskit versions or completely removed. Can anyone point to where I could find it, if it has been relocated, or with what can I replace it with in case it's been removed. Or if it doesn't matter and I should just chug along and not worry about the details so much.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Qiskit release notes](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/release-notes/0.25), `SamplePulse` has been deprecated in version 0.15 and removed in version 0.25.

You should use [`Waveform`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.pulse.library.Waveform) instead.

Comment: OK, thought that WaveForm would be the thing to use. Thanks for the answer!